# How do I average a column of values while excluding rows from a value from another column? PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to write a code for a data table in Powerbi that averages values of a table but categorizes them based on ID and Project but at the same time exclude a value from another column. Below is what I am trying to accomplish. Excluding Type "II" and averaging the values based on category columns [ID] and [Project]

[image]

Below is the code I am trying to write. What would be the best solution?

```
AVG = Calculate(AVERAGEX(Filter(Table, Table[Type] <> "II"), Table[Values]), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Project]))
```

Comment: A clearer example with test data would be great

Comment: Made a clearer example with test data